# Plotting 100% stacked graph issue

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I got a dataframe df5 with the following table which I read in from read_csv,

```
Week_Days,Category,Total_Products_Sold,Total_Profit
0.Monday,A,3221,9999.53
0.Monday,B,1038,26070.33
0.Monday,C,699,13779.56
0.Monday,E,3055,18157.26
0.Monday,F,47569,215868.15
0.Monday,G,2348,23695.25
0.Monday,H,6,57
0.Monday,I,14033,64594.24
0.Monday,J,13876,47890.91
0.Monday,K,3878,14119.74
0.Monday,L,243,2649.6
0.Monday,M,2992,16757.38
1.Tuesday,A,2839,8864.78
1.Tuesday,B,1013,26254.69
1.Tuesday,C,656,13206.98
1.Tuesday,E,2696,15872.45
1.Tuesday,F,43039,197621.18
1.Tuesday,G,2107,21048.72
1.Tuesday,H,3,17
1.Tuesday,I,12297,56942.99
1.Tuesday,J,12095,40724.2
1.Tuesday,K,3418,12551.26
1.Tuesday,L,243,2520.3
1.Tuesday,M,2375,13268.28
2.Wednesday,A,2936,9119.93
2.Wednesday,B,1061,26927.86
2.Wednesday,C,634,10424.05
2.Wednesday,E,2835,16627.35
2.Wednesday,F,46128,218014.59
2.Wednesday,G,1986,19173.64
4.Friday,H,24,233
4.Friday,I,17576,81648.75
4.Friday,J,16468,55820.9
4.Friday,K,4294,16603.39
4.Friday,L,440,4258.51
4.Friday,M,3600,20142.44
5.Saturday,A,4658,15051.13
5.Saturday,B,1492,38236.07
5.Saturday,C,1057,15449.7
5.Saturday,E,5335,29904.96
5.Saturday,F,79925,362120.61
5.Saturday,G,4324,44088.79
5.Saturday,H,26,933
5.Saturday,I,22688,106313.86
5.Saturday,J,21882,74725.11
5.Saturday,K,5402,20875.84
5.Saturday,L,458,4692.84
5.Saturday,M,4896,27769.68
6.Sunday,A,3429,11310.1
6.Sunday,B,1104,27282.99
6.Sunday,C,1051,11567.08
6.Sunday,E,3913,22740.63
6.Sunday,F,56048,259105.03
6.Sunday,G,3224,32528.39
6.Sunday,H,21,749
6.Sunday,I,15853,74876.77
6.Sunday,J,16072,55259.76
6.Sunday,K,4383,16058.36
6.Sunday,L,327,3348.82
6.Sunday,M,3551,20814.05
```

I want to plot 2 100% stacked bar charts for Total Products Sold and Total Profit each, where the x-axis is Week Days and the labels are the different Categories.

My code for Total Products Sold is

```
df5 = df5.set_index(['Week_Days', 'Category'])
df5 = df5.div(df5.sum(1), axis=0)
ax = df5[['Total_Products_Sold']].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, width = 0.3, figsize=(20, 10), colormap="RdBu")
patches, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1.0))
ax.set_xlabel('Week Days')
ax.set_ylabel('Products Sold')
```

The graph I got returned looks nothing I need.  It is not 100 stacked and the legend is Total Products Sold and not the different categories in Category.

[image]

Can someone please help?  Thanks.

Regards,
Lobbie

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The easiest way is to make a pivot table with the values you care about. Try something like this:

```
tps = df5.pivot_table(values=['Total_Products_Sold'], 
                      index='Week_Days',
                      columns='Category',
                      aggfunc='sum')

tps = tps.div(tps.sum(1), axis=0)
tps.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

For me this produces the following:

[image]

You can do the same thing for `Total_Profit` separately.

Comment: Hi hume, thank you and yes it worked now.  I was also thinking along the same lines after playing the data in an Excel pivot.  1 more question please.  The labels in the graph showed (Total Products Sold, A) (Total Products Sold, B) and so on.  Is it because I used -> patches, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels() ?  How can I fix this to show just A, B, C...?

Comment: Adding the following line after the pivot table should remove the first level of the columns multiindex (which is just 'Total_Products_Sold' in this pivot table): `tps.columns = tps.columns.droplevel()`