# 100% Stacked bar pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
In [12]: df
Out[12]:
         Date  Sales      Type
0  2020-01-01     10    hotdog
1  2020-01-01      5  icecream
2  2020-01-01      9      soda
3  2020-01-02      7    hotdog
4  2020-01-02      5  icecream
..        ...    ...       ...
89 2020-01-30      4  icecream
90 2020-01-30     11      soda
91 2020-01-31      7    hotdog
92 2020-01-31      3  icecream
93 2020-01-31     12      soda

[94 rows x 3 columns]
```

I need a plot like this:

[image: plot]

Here's what I've done so far:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Before-After'] = df['Date'] < '2020-01-15'
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Sales', index='Before-After', columns='Type', aggfunc=sum)
df2.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

This is what I'm getting:

[image]

How to make it 100% stacked?

Comment: There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36784336/python-pandas-plotting-100-stacked-graph-issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You take the sum of the values in the groups, but you need to normalize them to a percentage:

```
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Sales', index='Before-After', columns='Type', aggfunc=sum)
df2 = df2.div(df2.sum(axis=1), axis=0)*100   #divide each cell by the sum of the row, multiply by 100
df2.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image]